# What evolved to produce sweetness, plants or consumers?

Tags: evolution, botany, senses

I couldn't find an existing answer on this site, although I may be wrong.

**What evolved to produce "sweetness", a pleasant reaction to the presence of sugar?**
**(A)** Plants, using it to lure in consumers and spread seed
**(B)** Animals / consumers, which used sugar as a vital nutrient, to identify nutritious food, or
**(C)** Neither of the above; something else?

Comment: sounds like A and B could easily be answers - what do you think?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh I think either is plausible. I'm just wondering if there is one that can be proven or one that is widely accepted

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh seems to be A and B both are correct but both are hypothetical/ speculative. Even if we have an established theory for only 1; the other seemingly could not be avoided as false. But it seems more to me that sweetness as indication of food was evolved earlier; and later-on plants 'applied' it for their benefit. So NOT a complete egg-or-chicken situation.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the question "do plants evolved sweetness first or did animals evolved attraction to sweetness first?". When reading a question of the type "What evolved for ...", it sounds like you are searching for a physiological explanation but the suggested answer don't go toward this direction.

Comment: @Remi.b I'm not exactly sure how to answer that, the idea of something evolving in response to something else seemed somewhat clear to me; answer however you think you can explain what occurred.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

Seeking sugar evolved long before animals, before multicellular organisms even.
Plant evolved a strategy to exploit it much much later with the evolution of fruit and nectar.

Animals evolved to like the taste of sugar since it is the primary fuel almost all life metabolizes to live in an easy to digest form, literally a simple carbohydrate. plants use sugar substances as lures becasue that's what animals already wanted and plants were already making it. Also a lure is not going to evolve before the seeking behavior that would actually make it a lure. fruit and nectar are new sugar is one of the oldest metabolic compounds in existence.

Metabolizing glucose is one of the shared characteristics between Eukaryotes and Bacteria and is present in nearly all life,[source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9084754). Meaning it is was likely present in their common ancestor. This means plants and animals have been eating sugars since before they diverged into plants and animals. . Chemotaxis  of motile bacteria towards glucose is well understood, and likely predates the existence of eukaryotes. [source](http://chemotaxis.biology.utah.edu/Parkinson_Lab/projects/ecolichemotaxis/ecolichemotaxis.html)

The production of sugar by photosynthetic bacteria predates the merging of Eukaryotic cells and chloroplast ancestors. It was present in the Cyanobacteria that gave rise to chloroplasts, meaning sugars were produced long before plants existed. [source](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/bacteria/cyanointro.html) the attractive aspect was only exploited later with evolution of nectar and fruit.

Comment: *Plants have been making sugar since before they were plants and animals have been eating sugars since before they were animals.*.. Perhaps you should clarify this statement (make it scientifically accurate so that it is not misleading).

Comment: Please add valid references (with links) to support your claims. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.